# A rake task from a gem doesn't show up in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem with a list of rake tasks. I have this:

```
#/lib/tasks/my_gem.rake:

namespace :my_gem do
  task :task1 do
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

I install the gem to a rails application and run **rake -T**. And there's no task "task1" or anything related to "my_gem".

Answer (score 1):

Add a description, like so:

```
namespace :my_gem do
  desc "my task"
  task :task1 do
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it should still show up without the description, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev for me tasks don't show unless i give it a desc (Rails 5.0.2).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i do think you can run without a desc. But it doesn't show in the rake -T